# Magento order products in cart by category

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I would like to change the default order of the products in the cart. By default it sorts by the sequence the products are added to the cart.

But it would be way easier for me if I can sort them by category.

So let's say default way is this:

Product a (Snack)
Product b (Vegetables)
Product c (Snack)
Product d (Fruit)

I want it to be:

Product a (Snack)
Product c (Snack)
Product b (Vegetables)
Product d (Fruit)

Can someone guide me here in how to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have access to the back-end MySQL tables? Specifically to the `catalog_category_product_index` table?

Comment: Yes,  I can access the database.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `catalog_category_product`. You just have to call `UPDATE catalog_category_product SET position = {0} WHERE (category_id = {1} AND product_id = {2})` to update the positions.

Comment: Can you guide me a little more here. Do I have to call this in the function where the shopping cart retreives it's products?

Comment: No, you basically query your products for each particular category and use whatever method you need to create a new ordering, then you call the `UPDATE` query to set those orders. Then you need to go in to Index Management and update your Category Products index and the sire will be ordered the way you need it.

Comment: You're basically trying to generate a bunch of statements like this: `UPDATE catalog_category_product SET position = 12020 WHERE (category_id = 668 AND product_id = 15952);`.